# C# - Round numbers to 0 decimals

Tags: c#, rounding

I need to round numbers to 0 decimals (for a pagging system).

I've already tried something like this:

```
Math.Round(double1, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

If the double1 be 7,2 or 7,6 i need it to round for 8 but i'm not getting that.

Can someone help me, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`Math.Ceiling`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.ceiling.aspx) to always round up to the next integer:

```
double roundUp = Math.Ceiling(double1);
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exacly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `Math.Ceiling`, for some reason - you could do:

```
 public int Ceil(double x) {
  return (int) x + ((int) x < x ? 1 : 0);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

At your case.. Use p=1..

```
float RoundTo(float x, float p)
{
  float y = 1/p;
  return int((x+(1/(y+y)))*y)/y;
}

float RoundUp(float x, float p)
{
  float y = 1/p;
  return int((x+(1/y))*y)/y;
}

float RoundDown(float x, float p)
{
  float y = 1/p;
  return int(x*y)/y;
}
```